# Access to class attributes of parent classes

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, attributes

I would like to know what is the best way to get all the attributes of a class when I don't know the name of them.

Let's say I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4

class A(object):
    outerA = "foobar outerA"
    def __init__(self):
        self.innerA = "foobar innerA"

class B(A):
    outerB = "foobar outerB"
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.innerB = "foobar innerB"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
```

Using hasattr/getattr to get the "outerA" class field of my b instance works fine:

```
>>> print hasattr(b, "outerA")
>>> True

>>> print str(getattr(b, "outerA"))
>>> foobar outerA
```

Ok, that's good.

But what if I don't exactly know that b has inherited a field called "outerA" but I still want to get it?

To access b's inner fields, I usually use `b.__dict__` . To get `b.outerB`, I can use `b.__class__.__dict__` but that still doesn't show "outerA" among it fields:

```
>>> print "-------"
>>> for key, val in b.__class__.__dict__.iteritems():
...     print str(key) + " : " + str(val)
>>> print "-------\n"
```

Shows:

```
-------
__module__ : __main__
__doc__ : None
__init__ : <function __init__ at 0xb752aaac>
outerB : foobar outerB
-------
```

Where's my `outerA`?? **:D**

I am sure I can keep "climbing" the class hierarchy and get all the fields, but that doesn't seem like the greatest solution...

As there are hasattr(), getattr()... isn't there something like a **listattr()** that would give all the available attributes of an instance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `dir(b)`. The resulting list includes inherited attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `dir()` - it works just as well within code as in the shell.